# How to create a root login page for mysql in php and html

Tags: php, html, mysql, rdbms

I am trying to make a root login page for mysql in php and html but while executing the script it is not able to link with the mysql database.I am using mariadb server in ubuntu. here is the php code attached

```
<?php
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_NAME', 'Project');
 define('DB_USER','root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','123');

 $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to     connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 /*
 $ID = $_POST['user'];
 $Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/
function SignIn()
{
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if(!empty($_POST['user']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from      Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass']))
{
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'];
    echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";

}
else
{
    echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
}
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
SignIn();
}

?>
```

Comment: Make sure that you use MySQL and not MySQLi

Comment: What is the question and what is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you [escape your strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent an [sql injection attack](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: Also use some sort of [hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) - if you've never done this before, I'd suggest you find a tutorial online to learn about the security aspects of it

Comment: @Ifaruki I hope you meant the other way round!

Comment: You haven't told us what error or problem you're getting. "Not able to" isn't a fixable problem

Comment: But if you found this code from some tutorial I'm afraid you've found a very out of date version...try and find something more modern that used modern database libraries and shows how to properly parameterised the queries and also hash the passwords. This code is a security nightmare